# Haskell pattern matching a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

As the post title says, I'm defining the following function in Haskell:

```
prop_LeftInverse :: (Eq a, Eq b) => [(a,b)] -> Bool
prop_LeftInverse (x,y):(xs,ys) = undefined
```

which should take as input a list of tuples. I'm getting a `parse error in pattern` but I can't quite figure out what it is, and also haven't found any information about this specific case...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Almost right:

```
prop_leftInverse ((x, y):rest) = undefined
```

First of all, you need parentheses around the whole pattern.  Second, the first element in the list is a tuple, but the rest of the list is just a list of tuples, not a tuple of lists.

If you look at simple pattern matching on a generic list

```
head :: [a] -> a
head [] = error "Empty list"
head (x:xs) = x
```

This works all values of type `a`, or all types.  If you want a specific type, such as `Int`, you could do

```
headIsOne :: [Int] -> Bool
headIsOne (1:xs) = True
headIsOne _ = False  -- Here the _ matches anything
```

So, if you want to match a tuple:

```
addTup :: (Int, Int) -> Int
addTup (x, y) = x + y
```

we see that the pattern to match a tuple is exactly how we write one in code, so to match one at the beginning of list, we just have to match the first element with a specific pattern.

```
prop_leftInverse ((x, y):rest) = undefined
```

The rest of the list gets assigned to `rest` (although you can call it whatever you want).

---

**Another example**

If you wanted to grab the first two tuples:

```
myFunc ((x, y):(v, u):rest) = undefined
```

Or the first three:

```
myFunc ((x1, y1):(x2, y2):(x3, y3):rest) = undefined
```

By now I hope you can see the pattern (get it?)

Comment: That comma inside tuple pattern matching... Saved my day.

Comment: @ratijas glad it could help :)